# Calculation of evolution equation with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have near to no experience with mathematica, so this might seem pretty trivial.
I want to solve an Evolution equation, i.e. we have a function $f(t,x)$ and a differential operator $T(t,\partial_t)$. The equation is then

$T(t,\partial_t) f(t,x) = c$

As an example consider $T = t \partial_t$,the initial condition $f(1,x) = e^{x}$ and $c=1$. Then we have the differential equation

$\partial_t f(t,x) = \frac{1}{t} \rightarrow f(t,x) = f(1,x) + \log(t) = e^{x} +
 \log(t)$

Then I would want to plot $f$ for some fixed value of $t$, e.g. $f(2,x) = e^{x} + \log(2)$.
My first try would be something like

`NDSolve[{Derivative[f[t, x], t] == 1/t, f[1, x] == Exp[x]}, {x, 0, 3}, {t, 1, 2}]
Plot[Evaluate[f[2,x] /. %], {x, 0, 3}]`

But that doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D) instead of [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative), and you need to include the function to be solved for (`f`):

```
NDSolve[{D[f[t, x], t] == 1/t, f[1,x] == Exp[x]}, f, {x, 0, 3}, {t, 1, 2}];
Plot[f[2, x] /. %, {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

In this case, the [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate) is not necessary.

*(If you do want to use Derivative instead, it should be `Derivative[1, 0][f][t, x]`)*